# Itext:How to deal with itext 5.4.3?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to upgarde my code to itext 5.4.3.
it was written in earlir version of itext i.e 2.1.7.

i have problem while declaring table,paragraph and all stuffs.
my earlier code was like this::

```
Table tab = new Table();
tab.setWidth(100);
tab.addCell(new Paragraph("Sr. No."));
tab.addCell(new Paragraph("Candidate Name",new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD)));
tab.addCell(new Paragraph("Candidate Code",new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD)));
tab.addCell(new Paragraph("Login ID",new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD)));
tab.addCell(new Paragraph("Password",new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD)));
```

so please let me know the solution or link for the tutorials based on use of itext 5.4.3 version.

Comment: Import the new version of iText and use the new [API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/).

Comment: yes,i have the new version of itext but i dont know the syntax.because in this version the syntax of above code doesn't work.that's why i am in search of some good examples based on itext 5.4.3 API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [iText Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html).
Seems quite complete for what you are looking for.

Comment: it seems older one.because in latest release of 5.4.3.there is no method of table.addcell().

Comment: @amitsingh I used that example with 5.4.3 and runs without any problem. Also check the [PdfPTable API](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html)

Comment: yes,It works.thanks.some mistake was done by me that's why it was not working.your link is sufficient for me :)